# "Github contribution"-clone made with VueJs. Any logic improvements?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I took a shoot at writing a Github contribution clone using Vuej, tippy.js and tailwindcss.

Githubs looks like this: [image]

**My working clone looks like this:**
[image]

Its not an exact look-a-like but im getting there. I have received some feedback on using the library [date-fns](https://date-fns.org) to generate year, months and days, it seems that the data generation is scattered across the application.

At the moment i think my code is pretty readable but performance wise, i dont have a clue - i havent tested it a larger amount of data.

Here is the working example (and a [stackblitz fiddle](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-gdgttl-xqyqyq?file=src%2FApp.vue)):

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
      <div v-for="(month, index) in all_months" v-bind:key="month">
        <h1>{{ month }}, {{ getDaysInMonth(index) }}</h1>
        
        <div class="flex">
            <div v-for="day in getDaysInMonth(index)" v-bind:key="day" class="flex flex-col">
                <div class="flex flex-row">
                    <div class="mr-1"></div>
                    <div class="w-4 h-4 rounded-sm mt-1 bg-gray-300 shadow" 
                    :class="{'bg-green-300': test[whatDate(index, day, true)]}" 
                    :data-tippy-content='`${whatDate(index, day)}`'></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      whatDate: {{ whatDate(1, 22, true)}}
    </div>
  </template>
  
  <script>
  import tippy from 'tippy.js';
  import 'tippy.js/dist/tippy.css'; // optional for styling

  export default {
    mounted(){
        tippy('[data-tippy-content]')
    },
    // props: ['answers', 'correct_answer_count', 'wrong_answer_count'],
    data(){
      return{
        days: [],
        answers: {
            "06-Nov-22": {
                "total":24, "correct":17, "wrong":7},
            "14-Jul-22": {
                "total":26, "correct":24, "wrong":2},
            "13-Jul-22": {
                "total":21, "correct":14, "wrong":7},
            "09-Jul-22": {
                "total":30, "correct":23, "wrong":7},
            "06-Jul-22": {
                "total":4, "correct":3, "wrong":1},
            "05-Jul-22": {
                "total":13, "correct":11, "wrong":2},
            "04-Jul-22": {
                "total":164, "correct":148, "wrong":16},
            "03-Jul-22": {
                "total":7, "correct":4, "wrong":3},
            "27-Jun-22": {
                "total":1, "correct":1, "wrong":0},
            "22-Jun-22": {
                "total":10, "correct":9, "wrong":1}
            },
        } 
    },
    computed:{
        test(){
            const tempArray = {}
            const answers = this.answers
            Object.keys(this.answers).forEach(function(element, key) {
                tempArray[new Date(element).toLocaleDateString()] = answers[element]
            })
            return tempArray
        },
      all_months(){
        const month = Array.from({length: 12}, (e,i) => {
          return new Date(2022, i + 1, null).toLocaleDateString("sv", {month: 'long'})
        })
        return month
      }
    },
    methods:{
      getDaysInMonth(index){
        return new Date(2022, index + 1, 0).getDate();
      },
      whatDay(index, day){
        switch (new Date(2022, index , day).getDay()){
        case 0:
          day = "Sunday";
          break;
        case 1:
          day = "Monday";
          break;
        case 2:
          day = "Tuesday";
          break;
        case 3:
          day = "Wednesday";
          break;
        case 4:
          day = "Thursday";
          break;
        case 5:
          day = "Friday";
          break;
        case 6:
          day = "Saturday";
        }
        return day
      },
      whatDate(index, day, standardDate = false){
        if(!standardDate){
            return new Date(2022, index, day).toLocaleDateString("sv", {weekday: "long", year: "numeric", month: "long", day: "numeric"}) //.toDateString()
        }
        return new Date(2022, index, day).toLocaleDateString()
      }
    },
  }
  </script>
```